# Circular track race problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose A and B are running a 3km race in a circular track of length 300m. Speeds of A and B are in the ratio 4:3

How often and where would the winner pass the other?

In this situation it is easy to find the time after which the A crosses B for the first time. ( circumference/ relative speed)

Similarly the crossing point can be calculated.

How do I calculate the number of times A crosses B during the whole race?

Comment: Are they running in the same or opposite direction?

Comment: Not mentioned :(

Comment: " winner pass the order"???

Comment: Calculate how long the race will last:  (3,000/4 = 750 units of time).  Calculate when A will first meet B.  (x = ???? I dunno... you said you did it).  For all frames of reference everything is exactly like the start of the race.  So A will meet B in 2x,3x, etc.  How many times total?  750/x, of course.

Comment: Firstly my apologies for the wrong typo. Secondly thanks a lot for the explanation. Makes perfect sense. Just a question: Why do we take the total time taken by A (750/x) and not the time taken by B ?

Comment: This is how I have calculated the time taken to pass the first time: Assuming they are running in the same direction, relative speed is ( 4x - 3x = x ). Thus time taken is 300/x

Comment: Why the total time taken by A?  A is faster so A will win the race.  The race ends when A runs 3000 meters.  At that time all runners stop.  B will have only run 3/4 of the race (7.5 laps).

Comment: Got it!! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $A$ runs at 4m/unit of time (Call it a "u") and $B$ runs at 3m/u.

In $t$ units of  time runner $A$ will have run $4t$ meters and runner be will have run $3t$ meters.  If they are at the same point in the track then $4t = 3t + n*300$ were $n$ is how many more times around the track $A$ has run.  $n$ is also the number of times they have meet.

$4t = 3t + n*300$

$t = n*300$

The racers will be at the same point every 300 units of time.

How long does the race last?  Well, racer $A$ will win so $4T = 3000$ meters so $T = 750u$.

How many times will Player A outpace B if the meet every 300 u?  $750u/300u = 2.5$  So 2 times. (must be  whole number).

Another way to look at it is:  Every 4 laps A runs, B runs 3.  So in 4 laps A has met with B once.  And that time happens to be one an even lap! A runs 10 laps so he will meet with B, 2 times. (and be half a lap ahead at the end).

Another note:  In 300 units, $A$ will have run 1200 meters or 3 laps exactly.  $B$ will have run 900 meters or 3 laps exactly.

Answer (score 2):

You have the time between passes.  You can compute the total time $A$ is running by dividing the distance by his speed.  Now divide the running time by the time between passes and throw away the remainder.

Comment: Reframed the question. Maybe it makes a bit more sense now. Also shouldn't it be total running time of B divided by the time of pass? I apologise if this sounds really silly. But this has been evading me for a long time.

Comment: No, it should be A's running time, since he stops running at that time and doesn't pass B any more.  You can decide if you want to count any times that B passes A while A is sitting at the finish line.

Answer (score 1):

Describe the orbits of the two runners by
$$b(t)= e^{2\pi i t}\quad(0\leq t\leq 10), \qquad a(t)=e^{2\pi i(4t/3)}\quad(0\leq t\leq 7.5)\ .$$
We have a coincidence on the track when $t-{4\over3}t\in{\mathbb Z}$, i.e., when $t\in3{\mathbb Z}$. This happens at the common start $t=0$, then at $t=3$ and $t=6$. It follows that there are two actual passings, both occurring at the starting line.